# Unable to use Ookla's Speedtest command from python (invalid arguments)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, macos

I wish to use Ookla's [SpeedTest CLI](https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli) (after trying other Python libraries I didn't like).

I'd like to issue a "speedtest -f json" command from within a python script and parse the results.

I am currently stuck with the following code:

```
import subprocess


process = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/local/bin/speedtest', '-f json'],
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

which only populates the stderr variable stating that

```
[error] Invalid output format specified:  json
```

Given on the command line that syntax is good.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much

PS End goal will be monitoring the results and when they fall under a given threshold send me an email, but that's the final goal.

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work this way:

```
response = subprocess.Popen('speedtest -f json', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read()
```